# Displaying a pdf file from mongo to ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rendering, ejs, multer

I'm trying to display a pdf file of a records from mongo but I'm getting an `{"error":"Not Found"}` in the browser even though the path is correct.

Here's the code in my ejs template where i will display the file.

// view-files.ejs

```
<div class="container-lg">
        <h1 class="text-center">View PDF File</h1>
        <iframe src="<%= student.pdfFilePath %>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
```

And this is the table where there is a "view file" button that should display the specific file of a student based on the _id

// records.ejs

```
<tbody>
                                <% records.forEach(record => { %>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><%= record.lrn %></td>
                                    <td><%= record.studentName %></td>
                                    <td><%= record.gender %></td>
                                    <td><%= record.gradeLevel %></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="/systemAdmin/view-files/<%= record._id %>" >View Files</a>
                                    </td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                                <% }); %>
                            </tbody>
```

And this is route for "view-files.ejs" to display the file

````
    try {
        const studentId = req.params.id;
        const student = await Records.findById(studentId);

        console.log('Student:', student);

        if (!student) {
            res.status(404).send('Record not found');
            return;
        }
        const records = await Records.find();
        res.render('system_admn/view-files', { student });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error); 
        next(error);
    }
});```
````

[error in the browser when displaying the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhylw.png)